# Calling to api.vineapp.com always fails on server with 504 error

Tags: node.js, rackspace-cloud, rackspace, vine

I have a node app using vineapple to pull in vine posts.  On my local machine all pulls in fine but for some reason whenever I call out to api.vineapp.com on my server, it always fails.

I have tried also just using wget to see if I can access it but it is always returning back a 504 Gateway Timeout Error.

I also manually setup the hosts file so it uses the same ip that my local machine was hitting but all requests simply never get a response back.

Has anyone ever had this experience before with vineapple?  My server is simply a cloud server at rackspace and I know port 80 and 443 can be reached out on so not sure really where else to look.